# Unable to completely separate outputs of model in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to create a convolutional neural network that has two regression outputs, a score and a confidence. I have frozen the layers they have in common in the hopes that the addition of the confidence output doesn't change the score, but in my experiments it has. For the model with just the score, I used Xception and added a simple `GlobalAveragePooling2D` and `Dense(512)` layer then output a single number.

```
base_model = Xception(input_shape=(224, 224, 3), weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
predictions = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)

model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)

for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['mse','mae'], run_eagerly=True)
```

Here is what the end of `model.summary()` looks like:

[image]

When I fit it, the model produces good results.

But when I try to add a second output the result of the first becomes much worse. The new model gets trained off tuples where is first number is the same as the first model and the second number is a confidence value. The model is very similar to the one above.

```
base_model = Xception(input_shape=(224, 224, 3), weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)

score_x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
score_out = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='score_model')(score_x)

confidence_x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
confidence_out = Dense(1, name='confidence_model')(confidence_x)

model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=[score_out, confidence_out])

for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

losses = {'score_model': 'mae', 'confidence_model': 'mae'}
loss_weights = {'score_model': 1, 'confidence_model': 1} 

model.compile(loss=losses, loss_weights=loss_weights, optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['mse','mae'], run_eagerly=True)
```

When I look at `model.summary()`, it has twice as many trainable parameters as the previous model, which is exactly what I was expecting. Everything looks right to me so far.

[image]

But when I train this model the performance on the score is much worse. I was thinking it would be the same (within stochastic variation). After the first epoch, the loss from the first model is around 0.125. The `score_model_loss` from the second model is around 0.554. Clearly I'm not completely separating the models. What am I missing?

Comment: Your optimization process is not separated. It's harder to optimize two objectives than 1.

Comment: Two things I can think of.. 1) double-check that the base-model layers are indeed frozen in `model` and 2) try setting `loss_weights['confidence_model'] = 0.` to see if that makes things better (if so, try increasing it only slowly)

Comment: Wouldnt it make sense to just build 2 separate models instead if the goal is not to optimize them together?

Comment: @AkshaySehgal for efficiency I would like to have a single model produce both outputs.

Comment: Zooming out a bit, I don't know your specific application, but I would never try to fit confidence/variance as a point estimate (MSE, MAE, ...). Instead, I would use an objective like KL-divergence. To fit means and variances jointly.

Comment: @Kris I'll run some experiments and see how it goes.

Comment: @jss367 there is nothing efficient about it. Optimizing 2 goals together is a much harder process. Infact, optimizing for 2 goals together is actually a completely different problem than optimizing 2 independent goals separately

Comment: In the model space, you are essentially trying to find that ONE model that minimizes 2 losses together. while IIUC, you want to find optima for 2 losses independently which might be more efficiently modelled by 2 separate models.

Comment: If you really want to completely separate the 2 training processes but still have them in the same computation graph, then you may want to use a lamba layer to copy the input 2 times then have completely independent computation graphs (whose weights will be trained independently).

Comment: One minor thing.. your dense layers have large numbers of weights. It might help to squeeze in a dropout layer (depending on the size your dataset etc)

Comment: Let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal In general, your remarks are correct, but in this case the optimization process should be separated due to the fact that the joint weights are (supposedly) frozen.

Comment: Basically `grad_x ( f(x) + g(y) ) = grad_x f(x)` and `grad_y ( f(x) + g(y) ) = grad_y g(y)`

Comment: @AkshaySehgal by more efficient I mean that once in production it will be more efficient. I need both of these numbers and I'm going to run this model at a huge scale, so I would rather them share feature extraction and just have their own fully connected layers at the end to do regression.

Comment: That makes sense. let me see what i can suggest as an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** This answer will work well only because the layer that do the feature extraction are frozen. As @Akshay Sehgal  stated in the comments :

> optimizing for 2 goals together is actually a completely different problem than optimizing 2 independent goals separately

In that case, we are optimizing for 2 goals separately.

---

The easiest solution is probably to write a custom training loop with 2 `tf.GradientTape`, one for each goal. Lets consider this really simple example:

#### Dummy data

Let's create some random Data

```
import tensorflow as tf

X = tf.random.normal((1000,1))
y1= 3*X + 1
y2 = -2*X +2

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X,y1,y2)).batch(10)
```

#### Creating a model with 2 outputs

In that example, I skip the feature extraction step, as a simple linear regression will work for the data. But as your feature extractor network is frozen, the example is similar.

```
inp = tf.keras.Input((1,))
dense_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, name="objective1")(inp)
dense_2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, name="objective2")(inp)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inp, outputs=[dense_1, dense_2])

# setting up the loss functions as well as the optimizer
opt = tf.optimizers.SGD()
loss_func1 = tf.losses.mean_squared_error
loss_func2 = tf.losses.mean_absolute_error
```

Note the name given to the two dense layers: I will use them later to retrieve the appropriate weights.

#### Getting the weights to optimize

We can use the name set before to retrieve the variable belonging to each objective :

```
var1, var2 = [],[]
for l in model.layers:
    if "objective1" in l.name:
        var1 += l.trainable_variables
    if "objective2" in l.name:
        var2 += l.trainable_variables
```

#### The training loop

You simply need to tapes, one for each objective. You can use different optimizer as well, if it makes the training better.

```
counter = 0
for x, y1, y2 in ds:
    counter += 1
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape1, tf.GradientTape() as tape2:
        pred1, pred2 = model(x)
        loss1 = loss_func1(y1, pred1)
        loss2 = loss_func2(y2, pred2)
    grad1 = tape1.gradient(loss1, var1)
    grad2 = tape2.gradient(loss2, var2)
    opt.apply_gradients(zip(grad1, var1))
    opt.apply_gradients(zip(grad2, var2))
    if counter % 10:
        print(f"Step : {counter}, objective1: {tf.reduce_mean(loss1)}, objective2: {tf.reduce_mean(loss2)}")
```

If we run the training, we get:

```
Step : 1, objective1: 4.609124183654785, objective2: 2.6634981632232666
[...]
Step : 99, objective1: 7.176481902227555e-14, objective2: 0.030187154188752174
```

The principle advantage training that way is that you just need to extract the features once for the two objectives.

Comment: This looks good. I'm still testing it but I'll make sure to respond before the bounty period ends.